# Sql Server SUM function with Int and Decimal Conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Recently I was Playing with SQL Server data types, and a Large number of data in the table and trying to figure out the Performance with Varchar and Numeric data. But, I got some error which I don't think should not have been but it is. My problem is below :

I have a table :

```
create table sa(f1 varchar(100))
```

I have a Stored Procedure that Inserts 100000 data into the table :

```
create proc sad
as
begin
    declare @i int=0
    while @i<100000
    begin
       insert into sa values(@i)
       set @i=@i+1
    end
end


exec sad
```

And I have tested the following:

```
select CONVERT(int,f1) from sa  //Works Fine, i tested after the Problem
select sum(convert(int,f1)) from sa  //Didn't Worked, So i tested above and Below
select sum(convert(decimal(18,2),f1)) from sa //And, it again works fine
```

But, When I sum Converting F1 to Int, it shows me an error.
But, when I only select Converting to Int it's fine.
And, when I sum Converting F1 to decimal it works Fine.

What is the SUM function data type?
On the Above data, it works well with Decimal but not Int?
Why?

I'm Getting the Following error

**Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.**

Comment: Please copy and paste the error you get...

Comment: Sorry,...I edited my question with the error i got

Comment: I was trying to findout the Performance issues, while Using Varchar and Numeric data-type

Comment: Could the value of your sum be exceeding 2 billion?

Comment: Ya, it is 4999950000.00 which converting to Decimal i can see. But, Does the SUM function data type also converted into INT then?

Comment: If you are summing `int`, SUM will be an `int` but if you are summing `decimal`, SUM will be a `decimal`. For more detail, see my answer below...

Comment: Did you get all the info you needed to answer the q?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MS documentation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql), the `SUM()` function returns values of a different type, according to the datatype of the column you are adding: if the column is of type `int`, `tinyint`, or `smallint`, then SUM returns values of type `int`.

Converting to `bigint` or `decimal` makes `SUM()` return a larger datatype, this explains why in that case you have no overflow.

Comment: Ok, then the Sum depends on the Column data type we are summing. Thank You. It makes me clear.

Answer (score 7):

You're summing as `INT` which has a range that cannot hold that sum.

The `DECIMAL` can.

The sum of all values from 1 up to 99999 is 4999950000, the maximum INT value is 2147483647, less than half of what the sum ends up as.

When you sum INT's, you're getting a new INT. When you're summing DECIMAL's, you're getting a new DECIMAL, so the input type defines the output type.

You can switch to using `bigint` instead, and it should "be fine".

Also, on a second note, **please don't store numbers as text**!

Comment: Ya, i should not. But, Why? Do the SUM function derive its data type to an INT when i convert it?

Comment: Yes. Input is INT, output is INT.

Comment: How, Sum depends on INT, here Convert into INT works Well. And, Convert into Decimal Also Works well. then, why Summing(int) didnt works however it can Convert but why sum works Decimal?

Comment: SUM operation somehow depend on the Inner Data Typoe

Comment: The sum overflows, as the error message says. Try summing all the values from 1 to 10, and staying under 5. It's the same problem. The INT datatype cannot hold the sum, it's too large for it.

Answer (score 2):

Expect you have exceeded the maximum `int` value that SQL Server allows (2,147,483,647) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql.

Decimal allows a far higher limit of up to 10^38 - 1 (i.e. 1 with 38 zeros after) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql.

However, if the values are of type `int`, I wouldn't recommend converting to `decimal`. `Decimal` values are useful when you have figures with possible numbers after the decimal place with a known precision and scale (e.g. for currency, percentages etc.) As another poster has suggested, the best conversion here would be to a `bigint`:

```
select sum(cast(f1 as bigint)) from sa
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your resulting sum is too big for `int`, use `bigint`, also check [int, bigint, smallint, and tinyint (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)

```
select sum(convert(bigint,f1)) from sa
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),SUM(0))
```