# Getting sum total of column values in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in SQLite with this structure:

```js
 String CREATE_TOTAL_PRICE = "CREATE TABLE " + TOTAL_PRICE + "("
                + KEY_TPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_TPRICE + " REAL" + ")";
```

I am trying to get the sum total of all column values of column KEY_TPRICE.
I am using this method which seems to work:

```js
 public int getTotalOfAmount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM " + TOTAL_PRICE, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int i = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
        return i;
    }
```

But the problem comes when the value is being displayed.

You see i have data input as `50.01,5.5` and when getting the sum total i get `55` which is not really the case.

The real total is `55.51` when i run the query externally.

I have tried setting `REAL,INTEGER, FLOAT,DOUBLE` as my column data type but still

What exactly is rounding up my figures? Please asssist me with suggestions.

Comment: have you tried `getFloat(0)` instead of `getInt(0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are receiving 55 because you are reading it as "int"

```
int i = c.getInt(0);
```

That's why it is being "converted" to int (55).

According to question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17947203/4860513 , it seems that SUM() will return a number in the same format of the column that you are reading. So, try it to read is a double/float and share the result:

```
 float i = c.getFloat(0);
 double i = c.getDouble(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You better save the price as TEXT in the database, and when calculating the sum, cast them to double or BigDecimal for accurate result.

Comment: Any consequences of using REAL?

Answer (score 1):

Change your return value to double

```
 public int getTotalOfAmount() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(total_price) FROM " + TOTAL_PRICE, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        double i = c.getDouble(0);
        c.close();
        return i;
    }
```